# Control speed of linear actuator servo

Tags: servo

I have a [linear actuator](http://www.firgelli.com/Firgelli_Technologies_PQ12_R_p/pq12-r.htm) that I want to be able to slow down. Right now, the shaft moves too quickly. I'm not sure how to do this. I was looking into `varSpeedServo.h` library but couldn't implement it.

```c
//Includes
#include <Servo.h> 

//Defines
#define LINEARACTUATORPIN 9        //Linear Actuator Digital Pin



const int button1Pin = 4;     // the number of the pushbutton pin


// variables will change:
int button1State = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status


Servo LINEARACTUATOR;  // create servo objects to control the linear actuator

int linearValue = 10000;   //current positional value being sent to the linear actuator. 

void setup() 
{ 
  //initialize servo/linear actuator objects
  LINEARACTUATOR.attach(LINEARACTUATORPIN, 1050, 2000);      // attaches/activates the linear actuator as a servo object 

  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(button1Pin, INPUT);   


  //use the writeMicroseconds to set the linear actuators to their default positions
  LINEARACTUATOR.writeMicroseconds(linearValue); 

} 

void loop() 
{ 

  // if the pushbutton is pressed set the linear value
  button1State = digitalRead(button1Pin);
  if (button1State == HIGH) {    
    // set the position value  
    delay(2000);  
    linearValue = 1050; 

  } 

    if (button1State == LOW) {    
    // set the position value  
    linearValue = 2000;  
  } 

  //use the writeMicroseconds to set the actuator to the new position
  LINEARACTUATOR.writeMicroseconds(linearValue); 
delay(3000);  
}
```

Comment: Also see  [Change Servo Speed With RedBearLabs BLE Shield](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/20810)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like the following?

```
#define STEP 50

void loop() 
{ 

  // if the pushbutton is pressed set the linear value
  button1State = digitalRead(button1Pin);
  if (button1State == HIGH) {    
    // set the position value  
    if (linearValue > 1050)
       linearValue = max(linearValue-STEP,1050) ; 

  } 

    if (button1State == LOW) {    
    // set the position value  
    if (linearValue < 2000) 
       linearValue = min(linearValue+50,2000) ;  
  } 

  //use the writeMicroseconds to set the actuator to the new position
  LINEARACTUATOR.writeMicroseconds(linearValue); 
  delay(100);  
}
```

By changing the STEP value (or the delay in the next-to-last line) you can change the speed of the servo.